# Show that there cannot exist an embedding from $S^1 \to \Bbb R$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that there cannot exist an embedding from $S^1 \to \Bbb R$.

An embedding is defined to be a homeomorphism onto it's image. If we suppose that such an embedding would exist call it $f : S^1 \to f(S^1)$, then as $S^1$ is connected the continuous image $f(S^1)$ is also connected.

Now for any point $p \in S^1$ we know that $S^1 \setminus \{p\}$ is connected as it's homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ which is connected and therefore has only one component, but $f(S^1) \setminus \{p\}$ is now a space with two components and therefore $f$ cannot be an embedding as it should be an homeomorphism, but by deleting a point we end up with an homeomorphism between space of one component and one with two components.

Is this kind of point removal argument satisfactory here or is there alternative ways to conclude?

Comment: I don't know if you can argue that $f(S^1)\backslash \{p\}$ has two components, as you could remove an endpoint.

Comment: I think you need to use the fundamental group, you can argue that any connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is simply connected, so $f(S^1)$ needs to be simply connected, so it can't be homeomorphic to $S^1$, as $S^1$ is not simply connected.

Comment: @linkja Or you can simply remove a point $p$ which is not an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were told in the comments, if the point $p$ that you remove from $f\left(S^1\right)$ is an endpoint, your argument fails. Of course, you can say that $f\left(S^1\right)$ is an infinite set, and that therefore you can always remove a point which is not an endpoint. I think that this is the simplest and shortest proof.

Comment: I think you can actually argue that you cant remove an endpoint as if $f(S^1)$ were homeomorphic to  $S^1$ it would be open and so doesn't have any endpoints, right?

Comment: @linkja If $f\left(S^1\right)$ were homeomorphic to $S^1$, then it would be closed, since $S^1$ is compact. I don't see why is it that you claim that it would have to be open.

Comment: Ahh yeah right, I thought it needed to be open because $S^1$ is open, as it is the whole space, and $f(S^1)$ needs to be open as a set of itself as a subspace, but then it is always open and doesn't need to be open in $\mathbb R$, my mistake